# How to concatenate Terminal filter with Junit filter

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Hello i have the below CucumberOptions on my Junit Runner:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber_parallel.json", "junit:target/cucumber_parallel-junit-report.xml",
        "rerun:target/failed_scenarios/failed_parallel_once.txt", "timeline:target/timeline"},
        features = {"classpath:features/parallel"},
        tags = "(not @Ignored)",
        glue = {"com.intrasoft.swp.trader.stepdefs"},
        monochrome = true)
```

and we use maven command to execute the suites

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@one"
```

right now the tag passed from the Terminal command overwrites the one set on Junit.

what I would is that when filter.tags are set on the maven command the filter that will be used is

`@one and (not @Ignored)`

the concatenations of both filters.

i would like this because user execute it manually and forgot to specify the @Ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Cucumber runner cannot merge options from different sources. It loads options from 4 sources:

1. from propfety file
2. from annotation
3. from environment variable
4. from system variable

Each time on a given step it completely overrides the values configured on previous step.

Comment: So the solution is create runner on the fly ?

Comment: Not necessarily on the fly. You could implement your own runner and have it in your codebase. But this will require certain coding skills.